# How to store file in cocoa application then access it later to encrypt

Tags: cocoa, file, macos, encryption, aes

I have a file selector in my cocoa application, but when you hit the "Select" button I don't believe it actually stores, or uses that file. I need to use that file later to encrypt it. The user selects a file, enters a password in an NSSecureTextfield. Though this is impossible if I have no file to work with, how can I ACTUALLY select/use a file? I need to encrypt (256 bit AES) with the contents of that file. Once I actually store it, how would I access the data to encrypt it. It wouldn't necessarily be a text file, but maybe a sound file perhaps.

Thanks so much for your help

Comment: What do you mean by “file selector”: An open panel, or a save panel? It's not clear what you want to do; I can tell that selecting a file is involved, that you have “no file to work with” for some unspecified reason, and that encryption is involved, but beyond that, I can't figure out what your intent is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you'll first have to use a class like NDAlias (https://github.com/nathanday/ndalias) to create a "dynamic" link to your file. This is a link that will be maintained even if the file is in the meantime renamed or moved (on the same volume). It's very easy to use:

```
//store the alias
NDAlias *alias = [NDAlias aliasWithPath:pathToYourFile
                               fromPath:NSHomeDirectory()];

//do whatever you want

//later, restore the path (possibly the path has changed)
NSString *path = [alias path];
```

**Note:** If you want to just read the contents from the file right away, without doing anything in the meantime, there is of course no need for NDAlias at all.

To read data from the file, you just do:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

To do AES-256 encryption, the SSCrypto framework (http://septicus.com/products/opensource/) is your best friend. It's also very easy to use:

```
NSString *somePassword = @"somePassword"
NSData *passwordData = [somePassword dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

SSCrypto *sscrypto = [[SSCrypto alloc] initWithSymmetricKey:passwordData];
[sscrypto setClearTextWithData:data];

NSData *encryptedData = [sscrypto encrypt:@"aes-256-cbc"];
```

And to decrypt this data you do this:

```
NSString *somePassword2 = @"theSamePassword"
NSData *passwordData2 = [somePassword2 dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

SSCrypto *sscrypto2 = [[SSCrypto alloc] initWithSymmetricKey:passwordData2];
[sscrypto2 setCipherText:encryptedData];
NSData *decryptedData = [sscrypto2 decrypt:@"aes-256-cbc"];
```

Comment: What do you mean? I only mentioned the SSCrypto framework. Are there any other frameworks you are considering? SSCrypto should contain a readme file containing instructions on how to use it with Xcode.

Comment: Just to confirm, adding the SSCrypto Framework would make the following error go away, right?: Command /Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1

Comment: I don't know for sure because that could happen for various reasons. Can you try adding the framework and see what happens? Hopefully the error goes away.

Comment: Sure let me try that, I'll let you know what happens. Thanks for all the help

Comment: It keeps giving me that error. Because I am supposed to build it under "Deployment," but it fails because of that error. Thanks

Comment: It's really hard to tell what the source of this error is without seeing any code at all. In this case, the whole project might be needed since it might have to do with framework importing issues. Did you try creating a simple test application that uses SSCrypto?

Comment: Actually I downloaded it a again, and built it and it worked, however, I can't figure out how to actually build it as a framework, so I can copy it into my project. It says its under build/deployment, but I can't find it.

Comment: Try finding the SSCrypto.framework target in the Xcode project, right-clicking on it and doing "Show in Finder". Since Xcode 4, compiled projects often go into a separate folder someplace else.

Comment: Alternatively, you can just import the SSCrypto.m and SSCrypto.h files directly into your project. Then click on the Project in the sidebar (in Xcode 4), click your app target, and under "Link Binary with Libraries" add both libcrypto.dylib and libssl.dylib. This is probably the easiest way, as it doesn't require any compiling of a framework. I personally use this method.

Comment: I did exactly what you said and it gives me the error use of undeclared identifier "SScrypto"

Comment: You did import the SSCrypto.h header file into your file, right?

Comment: I really think you should read my code carefully again, and note that these are just snippets of code that you should adapt your own situation. If you try to really **understand** it, it should be clear what "data" is supposed to be, and if it's not being found you should create it yourself. (E.g., in one of the snippets above I showed how to read data from a file.) I recommend you sit back now, look at the code, and try to actually understand what is going on. Just copy-pasting it over without understanding it won't do any good :)

Comment: By the way, if I needed to actually tell you that you need to include a header file to make a class work, it could indicate that you really need to study some more about the Objective-C language, because including a header file is supposed to be a very basic thing.

Comment: Not meaning to be rude, by the way. Just some friendly advice :)

Comment: I know what a header and main file is. Sorry, I do actually understand what is going on, I'm new to encryption however. Your right though I should take a step back to actually understand the code.

Comment: And by the way, header files are for variable declarations, it is actually possible to have an application with no header whatsoever as in not declaring anything.

Comment: And when you said did you import SSCrypto.h into the file, It was already in my project, I just forgot to write "Import SSCrypto.h" in my AppDelegate. Also, I hate copy and pasters. I don't do that.